# Multiple outbound stdout channel adapter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">


    <!-- message producer / a Spring Integration wrapped Java Standard input 
        stream -->
    <int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="producer"
        channel="messageChannel" />

    <!-- a pair of message consumers / a pair of Spring Integration wrapped 
        Java Standard output streams -->
    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter
        id="consumer1" channel="messageChannel" append-newline="true" />
    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter
        id="consumer2" channel="messageChannel" append-newline="true" /> 
    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter
        id="consumer3" channel="messageChannel" append-newline="true" /> 

    <int:poller id="defaultPoller" default="true"
        max-messages-per-poll="5" fixed-rate="200" />

    <!-- a pub/sub message channel -->
    <!-- <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="messageChannel" /> -->

    <!-- a direct channel without the queue, a pollable channel with the queue -->
    <int:channel id="messageChannel">
        <!-- <int:queue capacity="2" /> -->
    </int:channel>
</beans>
```

with the java source code:

```
public class Startup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/si-components.xml");
        while (true) {

        }

    }
}
```

However, when I run the above code and give input from stdin, I get only one response back in the stdout. What am I doing wrong. The source code is obtained from:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-integration-part-1-understanding-channels/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

The following was commented out:

```
<!-- a pub/sub message channel -->
<!-- <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="messageChannel" /> -->
```

Comment: I was just going to say that :) - when there is no channel bean, a simple `DirectChannel` is automatically declared (by default).